# Deploy Heroku Process Types to individual apps

Tags: heroku, docker

Is there a way to break a composite Heroku app with multiple process types and deploy as separate apps. Can I clone the app, and comment out the ProcFile for one or either process types and deploy it separately on two different containers?

Answer (score 0):

You could most definitely do that, although -- that's probably only a good idea if you plan on maintaining each of those codebases separately.

Instead, why not just scale up a specific number of each process type? For instance, let's say you have defined two process types: `web` and `worker`.

You could say:

```
$ heroku ps:scale web=2 worker=2
```

This would run 2 web dynos, and 2 worker dynos. Each of them will run in separate containers and have their own resources.

Comment: I am pushing these apps to Cloud Foundry and it tries to run them on the same container, which doesn't like it. Hence I have to break it... I am not sure if there is a way to instruct cloud foundry like heroku.